# How to echo html elements, inline

Tags: php, html, css

every second item needs to be on right side of the page, but inline with first item, so it would create 2x2 type grid of both echoed items.

I added some CSS like this 
.container{float:left; width:50%;} but it didn't work.

```
if ($file6 % 2 == 1)
{
echo '<div id="container">
    <div id="thumbnail">
            <a href="/images/tirgus/'. $file .'"  title="'.cleanString($file).'" class="thickbox"><img src="/images/tirgus/thumbs/'.$row['id'].'.jpeg" width="141" height="74" alt="image" /></a>
        </div>
    <br>
    <div id="info1"><sub>' .cleanString($file2).'</sub></div>
    <br>
    <div id="info2"><sub>Telefons: ' .cleanString($file3). '</sub><br><sub>email: '.cleanString($file4).'</sub></div><br>
      <div id="info3"><sub>Iepostoja:</sub> ' .cleanString($file5). '</div><br>
        </div><widgets><customization><css>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="template_faili/gallery.css"></css></customization></widgets>';
 }
 else if ($file6 % 2 == 0) {
 echo '<div id="container2">
    <div id="thumbnail2">
            <a href="/images/tirgus/'. $file .'"  title="'.cleanString($file).'" class="thickbox"><img src="/images/tirgus/thumbs/'.$row['id'].'.jpeg" width="141" height="74" alt="image" /></a>
        </div>
    <br>
    <div id="info1"><sub>' .cleanString($file2).'</sub></div>
    <br>
    <div id="info2"><sub>Telefons: ' .cleanString($file3). '</sub><br><sub>email: '.cleanString($file4).'</sub></div><br>
      <div id="info3"><sub>Iepostoja:</sub> ' .cleanString($file5). '</div><br>
      </div><widgets><customization><css>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="template_faili/gallery.css"></css></customization></widgets>';
  }
```

}

Comment: Please avoid echoing html elements in your php. This architecture is dirty, you'll soon find out later how cumbersome it is to manage code with this kind of style. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.container{float:left; width:50%;}
```

will be want you want. FYI, please **DO NOT** use duplicate `id`s in your html.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad example, from now I will try to differentiate ids, when asking for help.

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis - your id names are not offensive. jasonslyvia is warning you that you are applying the same id to multiple elements by the nature of outputting them in a loop. This is advice (also mentioned in my answer) that you need to apply to your actual code, not to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of showing how you would use a `modulo` to achieve this, you would want to do something like:

```
foreach($files as $file_count => $file) {
  if ($file_count % 2 == 0)
    {
    echo '<div class="thumb row">';

    }
    echo ' 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="/images/'. $file .'"  title="'.cleanString($file).'" class="thickbox">
                <img src="/images/'.$row['id'].'.jpeg" width="141" height="74" alt="image" />
                </a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="info"><sub>' .cleanString($file2).'</sub></div>
        <br />
        <div id="info"><sub>text ' .cleanString($file3). '</sub><br><sub>email: '.cleanString($file4).'</sub></div>
        <br />
        <div id="info"><sub>text </sub> ' .cleanString($file5). '</div>
        <br />
    </div>';

  if ($file_count % 2 == 1)
    {
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Note that the above will probably not work as-is with your script because I am using a made up array that loops with the value `$file` while your code appears to have the various values in separate arrays. The overall idea is this:

```
foreach($files as $file_count => $file) {
```

Loops over each image/file you are wanting to output, starting at 0, so that :

```
$file_count % 2 == 0
```

indicates the first of two pair and

```
$file_count % 2 == 1
```

indicates the second of two pair.

So *before* the first of two are output, you start a container div such as:

```
<div class="thumb row">
```

Then you output your interior html as you already are, using the same html for both thumbnails.

and *after* the second of two are output, you close that div via:

```
</div>
```

Now each two of your thumbnail divs are wrapped in the `thumb row` container div, allowing you to apply css such as:

```
.thumb.row .container {
      display: inline-block;
 }
```

which will line them up side by side but still break on the outer `row` div.

Also, in addition to this being an ill-advised approach, you should not be setting the `id` attribute inside a loop, as this will set the same `id` to multiple elements, which is invalid HTML. Instead, update the code to use `class` which can be applied to multiple elements.

Comment: So I found solution, by adding multiple css 
gallery css - 
.container1{float:left; width:50%;}
and gallery2.css -
.thumb.row .container {
      display: inline-block;
 }
.container2{float:right; width:50%;}

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of better solutions. That was a given. The above works with the parameters you gave, which I thought was interesting enough to describe a possible solution. You could also achieve this without floats at all, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Each div need to use different classes/ids, where the inline behavior is defined or not.

```
$col[0] = 'class1';
$col[1] = 'class2';

for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

    $output .= '<div class="'. $col[$i%2] . ' >';

}
```